# Can't open Google Earth Engine scripts from journal articles

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to launch GEE scripts from a few journal articles, but once opening the code editor, I can't access the assets other authors worked with to see the full analysis. Here is an example, this code is from an article published in *Remote Sensing* : https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3a2d589395e4118d97bae3e85d09106

The error messages state that the collection assets ('ft:1POjOubAf8ZSvmMW3Ml3Ka3EUBt-5wY1eUg_J-04E' and 'ft:1goDR2acd9mOOaY3ha092MU_NOOMRvTh0sIApn_od') are not found.

I believe the code editor doesn't load the assets used by the author, does that mean that the author didn't allow the assets to be public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assets in the code are Google Fusion Tables (you can tell by the `ft:` at the beginning of the asset ID). Unfortunately Google [dropped support](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-fusion-tables-to-be-shut-down-on.html) for Fusion Tables at the end of 2019 and they are no longer accessible as assets within Earth Engine.

Perhaps you could contact the authors of the paper to see if their assets are accessible in a different way. Good luck!